# Imaginary time to solve Schrodinger equation

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, simulation, physics

I'm new to programming and I'm currently trying to create code that simulates the evolution of an initial wave function by solving the 1D Schrodinger equation using the split operator method. In my code, however, the wave function is static.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

# Define problem parameters
L = 10  # Box size
N = 1000  # Number of points on the grid
dx = L/N  # Spacing between points
x = np.linspace(0, L, N)  # Position vector

# Define the potential V(x)
def potential(x):
    return 0.5*x**2

# Define time step and number of iterations
dt = 0.01
num_iterations = 1000

# Define the initial wave function
psi = np.exp(-0.5*(x-5)**2)

# Create the figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Define the plot of the squared magnitude of the wave function
line, = ax.plot(x, np.abs(psi)**2, color='blue', lw=2)

# Set axis labels
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('$|\psi(x)|^2$')

# Define the update function
def update_func(i):
    # Evolve the wave function in imaginary time
    for j in range(50):
        psi = psi * np.exp(-1j*potential(x)*dt/2)
        psi = np.fft.fft(psi)
        psi = psi * np.exp(-1j*(np.pi/L)**2*dt)
        psi = np.fft.ifft(psi)
        psi = psi * np.exp(-1j*potential(x)*dt/2)
    
    # Update the plot of the squared magnitude of the wave function
    line.set_ydata(np.abs(psi)**2)
    ax.set_title('Iteration %d' % i)
    
    return line,

# Create the animation
animation = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_func, frames=num_iterations, interval=50)

# Save the animation as an mp4 file
animation.save('animation.mp4', fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])

# Show the animation
plt.show()
```

I would like to know what should be changed to make the evolution of the wave function visible over time.

Comment: I have tried running your code and got this warning: UserWarning: Animation was deleted without rendering anything. This is most likely not intended. To prevent deletion, assign the Animation to a variable, e.g. `anim`, that exists until you have outputted the Animation using `plt.show()` or `anim.save()`. Do you get the same? Does it help?

Comment: It looks like you're plotting a sort of "stationary state", `abs(psi)` stays practically constant throughout all iterations. Add the real and imaginary parts separately to the plot and you will see.